# Is there a way to use $index in angular as the model in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory that I am pushing values to from my controller my controller.

```
.factory("Inputs", function(){

    var inputs = {

    };

    inputs.editors = [0];

    return inputs;

})
```

I want to use **$index** as the model when I loop through it like so

```
<div class="texteditors">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="editor in app.inputs.editors">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="{{$index}}" ng-model="inputs.editors[{{$index}}]" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

but it won't evaluate, the only way I was able to get it to evaluate is like this:

but now its a string it evaluates to **inputs.editors['0']**

I want to then loop through the ng-models and evaluate them {{inputs.editors[0]}} to how ever many text areas are added.  I am not sure if I explained properly.

Should I use directive to create the binding, how would I be able to evaluate the textareas and models that are being generated from pushing the values to the factory?

Comment: Did you try using ng-model like this: ng-model="inputs.editors[$index]"? (without curly brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/ogJBVm

A few things were wrong with your markup.

You also need to add `track by` to your `ng-repeat`, otherwise you will lose focus every time the model changes because the textarea is recreated by the `ng-repeat`.

HTML:

```
<div class="texteditors" ng-controller="MyCtrl as app">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="editor in app.inputs.editors track by $index">
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="app.inputs.editors[$index]" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="editor in app.inputs.editors track by $index">
        <div>{{app.inputs.editors[$index]}}</vid>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Inputs) {
    this.inputs = Inputs;
})
.factory("Inputs", function(){
    var inputs = {};

    inputs.editors = ['foo', 'bar'];

    return inputs;

})
```

Comment: Thanks that was just what I need I really appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

You only need the curly brackets when you are dealing with strings. As @DimaGimburg also said, get rid of them in your ngModel.

```
<div class="texteditors">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="editor in app.inputs.editors">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="{{$index}}" ng-model="inputs.editors[$index]" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` expects an angular expression. That means that you don't need the `{{}}` notation.

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="{{$index}}" ng-model="inputs.editors[$index]" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

On the other hand, `name` doesn't expect an angular expression. Thats why you needed the `{{}}` there.

Comment: Yeah the issue I was having is it would not evaluate, I get it the ng-model is  and angular directive, name is an html attribute(directive) and is not expecting an expression but a string.